# validate value in parameter ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report in which a user is asked to enter a number. (parameter @number1 int).

How do I validate what the user entered?

eg. the number should be >0 and <99.

Is there some vaildation I could use? Or is there something to be done with expressions in 'available values'?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no validation available directly. The most common way to do this is to use a stored procedure to validate the input. You can also use a text box with conditional visibility to display a message to the user that the value is incorrect and put conditional visibility using the same logic on other report items to hide them when the user's input is incorrect.

Comment: `The most common way to do this is to use a stored procedure to validate the input.`      And how would I do that please?

Comment: Your dataset needs to be based on a stored procedure that accepts input. You pass the report parameter as an input parameter to the stored procedure in your dataset definition. Inside your stored procedure, you would need to write code to validate the number and return nothing if it's not valid. You would still want to do something in your report to explain why nothing gets returned - you can use the NoRowsMessage property of your data region to do this.

Comment: Thank you Stacia. I understand it now.You have been a good help!